# data is not inserting into database in codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter

actually i am having student records in $students array and there is another array within $students, whose name is skill[], which is a checkbox form field name, so pls tell me how to use json_encode and where.

input form

```
<td>ENTER SKILLS</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="php">php<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="dotnet">dotnet<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="java">java<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="ruby_on_rails">ruby_on_rails<br>
</td>
```

controller

```
 <?php
    public function insert(){
            if ($this->input->post('add')==true)
            {
 $student = array( 'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
 'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
 'skills' => $this->input->post(json_encode(skills)),
 'notes' => $this->input->post('notes'),
 'gender' => $this->input->post('gender') );
                    $result = $this->Student_info_model->insertStudent($student);
                    if($result==true){
                            echo "inserted";
                    }
                    else {
                            echo "Not Inserted";
                    }
            }
    }
    ?>
```

model

```
function insertStudent($student){   
    $this->db->insert('student_info_table', $student);  // insert data into "student_info_table" table` 
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

error

```
Error Number: 1048

Column 'skills' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `student_info_table` (`name`, `email`, `skills`, `notes`, `gender`) VALUES ('gailyn', 'quentin@gmail.com', NULL, 'dsas', 'male')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Comment: what is this: `$this->input->post(json_encode(skills))`? only skills?

Comment: Does it display "inserted" or "not inserted"?

Comment: Yeah, what goes wrong where?

Comment: skills[ ] is array within $student, and i am inserting $student into table, so please tell me how @PathikVejani

Comment: it should be `$skills`, print $skills array and see how it goes?

Comment: please check i have pasted the error i am getting@wallyk

Comment: To overcome this allow Null field from your DB

Comment: If you need code fix, Before assign it to array check its empty or not.

Comment: implode the `$skills` and then insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understand you want to get the array of skills from the http request and then to encode it and save it to your database. For that please use `json_encode($this->input->post('skills')` instead of `$this->input->post(json_encode(skills))`, so you first get the data, and then apply the json encoding over it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this : `json_encode($this->input->post('skills'))` You need to get the value of skills using input post and then need to convert it using json_encode